# angular trasnclude always adds as child, sibling required

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to do the transclude equivalent of `element.insertAfter`. What I am getting is basically `element.appendChild`. I would like the new element to share the same parent as the directive's element.

I would like

```
<div>
    <input with-button></input>
</div>
```

to become

```
<div>
    <input></input>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

but I get instead

```
<div>
    <input>
        <button></button>
    </input>
</div>
```

My directive's template looks like

```
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
<button></button>
```

and the directive looks like

```
angular
    .module('appy')
    .directive('withButton', withButton);

function withButton() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template'
    };
}
```

According to the docs this should work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, everything you declare as directive template will be put inside the element on which the directive is used. So in your case your template:

`<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
<button></button>`

Will go inside the:

`<input with-button></input>`

So, no wonder the button finishes inside your input.

Second thing, setting { transclude: true } means *"get everything from inside the element on which this directive is applied, and put it inside the element in the directive template on which ng-transclude is used*", in this case nothing since there is nothing inside 
`<input with-button></input>`
 (it has no children).

Comment: thanks for clarification. Sounds like I need to stick the directive on the input's parent element then. This doesn't feel like a great solution as I am interacting with the input in more ways than adding the button (I am also changing an attribute on the input), so it feels like the input element should be the element with the directive (rather than it's parent). Is there a way to do what I want avoiding the use of conclusion? I'm going to look at what `compile` does...

Comment: Yes, putting the with-button directive on the parent element (div) will give you the desirable output. On the other side, if you want to keep the directive on the input element, just throw away the { transclude: true } setting, throw away the directives template and instead create link function inside which you will `element.parent().append` the button.